# How to play audio by clicking a specific button with onKeyDown on React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on a Drum machine project where I am failing to pass a task. the task is:

> When I press the trigger key associated with each .drum-pad, the audio clip contained in its child  element should be triggered (e.g. pressing the Q key should trigger the drum pad which contains the string "Q", pressing the W key should trigger the drum pad which contains the string "W", etc.).

My code so far:

```
class Drumset extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyPress);
  }

  handleClick = (event) => {
    const audio = event.target.children[0];
    audio.play();
  };

  handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    if (
      event.key === "q" ||
      event.key === "w" ||
      event.key === "e" ||
      event.key === "a" ||
      event.key === "s" ||
      event.key === "d" ||
      event.key === "z" ||
      event.key === "x" ||
      event.key === "c"
    ) {
      const audio = event.target.children[0];
      audio.play;
      console.log("key pressed");
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="drum-machine" class="containerx box-middle">
          <div id="display" onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress}>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="drum-pad"
                    id="Heater-1"
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                  >
                    Q
                    <audio
                      class="clip"
                      id="Q"
                      src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3"
                      type="audio/mpeg"
                    ></audio>
                  </button>
```

My problem is that, whenever I press a key, the handleKeyPress() function works but the audio doesn't play (the console shows the print). How to play the audio when I press the associated button?

Comment: `audio.play;` does nothing, just references the function. Did you mean `audio.play()`?

Comment: @ggorlen getting an error in console that says audio.play() is not a function whenever I run the code.

Comment: @tanjimanim: Your problem is solved, use the answer that I provided. Also if you need any further explanation, do reach out to me brother :). Do accept the answer and rate as well for other developers to benefit from this :) Thanks

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather thanks brother

Comment: Most Welcome brother. Allah bless you :) Do please rate my answer and accept it also by clicking the tick icon. That will motivate me more and also help other developers with the same problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this : in your `handleKeyPress` handler,  `const audio = event.target.children[0];` does not target the `audio` element.

I have used `ref` to target the audio once user clicks on any of the keys mentioned in `handleKeyPress`. Also whenever we use `onKeyDown` synthetic event, we must use `tabIndex={0}`. Try the below code :)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class DrumSet extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyPress);
  }
  handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    console.log(event.key);
    if (
      event.key === "q" ||
      event.key === "w" ||
      event.key === "e" ||
      event.key === "a" ||
      event.key === "s" ||
      event.key === "d" ||
      event.key === "z" ||
      event.key === "x" ||
      event.key === "c"
    ) {
      this.myRef.current.play();
      console.log("key pressed");
    }
  };
  handleClick = (event) => {
    const audio = event.target.children[0];
    audio.play();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="drum-machine" className="containerx box-middle">
          <div id="display" onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress} tabIndex={0}>
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col">
                  <button type="button" className="drum-pad" id="Heater-1">
                    Q
                    <audio
                      className="clip"
                      id="Q"
                      src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3"
                      type="audio/mpeg"
                      ref={this.myRef}
                    ></audio>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: well this code is also giving me an error which is "Cannot read property 'play' of null". 
the line ```this.myRef.current.play();``` is causing this

Comment: It ran fine on my machine. I even tested it first.

Comment: Dear @tanjimanim: Is this component a part of biggest project or do you only have one component in your application. We can write better  code then to make it play.

Comment: sorry didn't notice this line now it works `ref={this.myRef}`. thanks
by the way, what does tabIndex do?

Comment: tabindex is simply the tabbing order. We have a tab key on the keyboard, when ever we click it, some DOM element is focused. tabindex="0" specifically  means that the element should be focusable in sequential keyboard navigation, after any positive tabindex values and its order is defined by the document's source order.. Since React events are not DOM events but Synthetic events, it is recommended to use tabindex with onKeyDown event.

Comment: also this line `ref={this.myRef}`, do I have to put it on all the audio tags?

Comment: Do you have other audio tags

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225993/discussion-between-imran-rafiq-rather-and-tanjim-anim).

Comment: yes, I have other buttons like the "Q" ones. it is a drum machine after all

Comment: Do you have other audio tags
If you have other audio tags, then using this.myRef will play all of those in one go whenever any of the keys mentioned in the onKeyPress() is clicked :) But since it is a brum machine.  You will need seperate refs for each key :)

Comment: I would suggest you learn a bit about how useRef works, then setting seperate useRef() would help you to tackle all those scenarios.However this may be too much code.

Comment: By the way, how many audios do you have in total?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it pass the tests without using the onKeyDown attribute. I think the solution is to use the keyCode event instead of the key event in the handle keyPress method. Have a look at my solution to this problem. I hope it helps, and feel free to ask any question.

```
`
import React from 'https://esm.sh/react@18.2.0'
import ReactDOM from 'https://esm.sh/react-dom@18.2.0'
```

const mapKeys = {
81 : 'Q',
87 : 'W',
69 : 'E',
65 : 'A',
83 : 'S',
68 : 'D',
90 : 'Z',
88 : 'X',
67 : 'C'
};

```
class DrumMachine extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
    };
    this.handlePlay = this.handlePlay.bind(this);
    this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyPress)
  }
 componentWillUnmount() {
   document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyPress)
 }
  handlePlay(id, audName) {
    document.getElementById(id).play();
    this.setState({name: audName})
    console.log("clicked")
  }
  handleKeyPress(event) {
    //console.log(event.keyCode);
    let key = mapKeys[event.keyCode];
    key && document.getElementById(key).play()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <section className="main">
      <div id="drum-machine">
        <div className="pads-div">
          <div 
            className="drum-pad"
            id="heater-1"
            onClick={()=>this.handlePlay("Q", "Heater 1")}
            //onKeyDown={ this.handleKeyPress}
            >Q
            <audio 
              id= "Q"
              src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3" 
            className="clip"
              >audio</audio>
         </div>
          <div 
            className="drum-pad"
            id="heater-2"
            onClick={()=>this.handlePlay("W", "Heater 2")}
            //onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress}
            //tabIndex={1}
            >W
            <audio 
              id="W"
              src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3" 
              className="clip"
              >audio</audio>
          </div>
          <div 
            className="drum-pad"
            id="heater-3"
            onClick={()=>this.handlePlay("E", "Heater 3")}
           // onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress}
            //tabIndex={2}
            >E
            <audio 
              id="E" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3" 
            className="clip"
              >audio</audio>
          </div>
          <div 
            className="drum-pad"
            id="heater-4"
            onClick={()=>this.handlePlay("A", "Heater 4")}
            //onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress}
            //tabIndex={3}
            >A
            <audio 
              id="A" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3" 
            className="clip"
              >audio</audio>
          </div>
          <div 
            className="drum-pad"
            id="clap"
            onClick={()=>this.handlePlay("S", "Clap")}
            //onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress}
            //tabIndex={4}
            >S
            <audio 
              id="S" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3" 
            className="clip"
              >audio</audio>
          </div>
          <div 
            className="drum-pad" 
            id="open-hh"
            onClick={()=>this.handlePlay("D", "Open HH")}
            //onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress}
            //tabIndex={5}
            >D
            <audio 
              id="D" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3" 
            className="clip"
              >audio</audio>
          </div>
          <div 
            className="drum-pad"
            id="kick-n'-hat"
            onClick={()=>this.handlePlay("Z", "Kick n' Hat")}
            //onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress}
            //tabIndex={6}
            >Z
            <audio 
              id="Z" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3" 
            className="clip"
              >audio</audio>
          </div>
          <div 
            className="drum-pad"
            id="kick"
            onClick={()=>this.handlePlay("X", "Kick")}
            //onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress}
            //tabIndex={7}
            >X
            <audio 
              id="X" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3" 
            className="clip"
              >audio</audio>
          </div>
          <div className="drum-pad"
            id="closed-hh"
            onClick={()=>this.handlePlay("C", "Closed HH")}
            //onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress}
            //tabIndex={8}
            >C
            <audio 
              id="C" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3" 
            className="clip"
              >audio</audio>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="display-div">
        <div id="display">
          <h4>{this.state.name}</h4>
        </div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<DrumMachine />, document.getElementById("root"))`
```

Here is my code pen. https://codepen.io/0PENJI/pen/oNPNxgK?editors=1111. You can follow me as you follow up the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, but this was 2 years ago and I have come so far now that it will take some time for me to understand the class-based components, as functional components are the way to go now. Also, I think you can refactor your code quite a bit. By making the data an array of objects with the keys, audio links and the keyname, just map it and use it.